# Google Fonts not loading sometimes

Tags: css, fonts

I am using Google fonts on my webpage but notice about 5% of the time the Google font seems to timeout and display the fallback font. So I stopped using it and I tried using @font-face with the downloaded font files on the server but I would have to add about 100 more lines of CSS for all the versions and load all the correct formats (.ttf,.eot etc) with the right CSS implementation. Too much of a headache. 
Is there a way I can tell the webpage to keep trying to get the font from Google until it loads? Or is there another solution?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<h1>Text</h1>
```

CSS

```
 h1
{
   font-family: 'Indie Flower', Georgia, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Add the 100 more lines of CSS. You should have your CSS organized, so just create a new CSS file and put the font declarations in there. 100 lines of code won't take that long to write. Besides, you can copy and paste most of the CSS.

Comment: You could try google's webfont loader, would not recommend using @font-face though, generally not the best for optimization. - https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the webfont loader

https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Little bit more set up but it works veery nicely and gives you a bit more control over loading fonts